# How to insert link into email

Tags: ruby, email

I'm trying to send an email from console, using Ruby.

```
def send_email
  yourdomain = 'whatever.com' # my site
  youraccountname = 'whatever@gmail.com' # my smtp gmail account
  yourpassword = 'whatever' # my smtp gmail account
  fromaddress = 'whatever@gmail.com'
  toaddress = 'whatever@hotmail.com' #recipient

  smtp = Net::SMTP.new 'smtp.gmail.com', 587
  smtp.enable_starttls

  smtp.start(yourdomain, youraccountname, yourpassword, :login) do
    smtp.send_message(report_msg, fromaddress, toaddress)
  end
end

def report_msg
  @msg ||= ["subject: #{report_subject}", report_body.html_safe].join("\n")
end
```

And `report_body` is kinda complex, but most important - it has stuff like this:

```
"[<a href='http://www.google.com'>some text</a>]".html_safe
```

"Google" is just sample link. And when recipient receives this the links are displayed as raw text. Like `<a href='http://www.google.com'>some text</a>`. Dunno how to make it work.

Dunno if that matters, but email body does not have `<html>` or `<body>` tags. And no html headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set the mimetype to "text/html" or "text/html; charset=utf-8"